# Unable to open symbol file. Error (20): Not a directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, dynamic-library

I am using ffmpeg library on android to stream live video feed. I have complied ffmpeg for android following [roman10 instructions](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/). The application is working correctly - it connects to the server, download the feed, transcode it, rescale it and displays on the device's screen. However after a certain random moment the app crashes with `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1`. I have used `ndk-stack` to find the source of the problem. Here is the crash dump:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.0.1/LRX22C/1602158:user/release-keys'
pid: 25241, tid: 25317, name: AsyncTask #5  >>> com.grzebyk.streamapp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x98e74c9c
Stack frame #00 pc 00047924  /data/app/com.grzebyk.streamapp-1/lib/arm/libswscale-3.so: Unable to open symbol file /Users/grzebyk/Documents/New_Eclipse_Projects/StreamApp/libs/armeabi/libStreamApp.so/libswscale-3.so. Error (20): Not a directory
Stack frame #01 pc 00034be8  /data/app/com.grzebyk.streamapp-1/lib/arm/libswscale-3.so (sws_scale+2648): Unable to open symbol file /Users/grzebyk/Documents/New_Eclipse_Projects/StreamApp/libs/armeabi/libStreamApp.so/libswscale-3.so. Error (20): Not a directory
```

My native code is located in the StreamApp.cpp file. For me it looks like the app is trying to access libswscale-3.so (part of the ffmpeg) located inside the libStreamApp.so. This seems weird for me…

All the ffmpeg's .so files are located in /libs/armeabi/lib*.so. Naturally this includes the "missing" libswscale-3.so. The most disturbing thing is a fact that the app is working perfectly, but it crashes suddenly and it does not need any specific trigger to do so.

What can I do to either put libswscale-3.so inside labStreamApp.so or to avoid referencing one .so file from another?

Answer (score 2):

It's rather simple, you have passed

> "/Users/grzebyk/Documents/New_Eclipse_Projects/StreamApp/libs/armeabi/libStreamApp.so/"

as a parameter for ndk-stack and obviously it's not a folder :) You should pass smth like

> "/Users/grzebyk/Documents/New_Eclipse_Projects/StreamApp/libs/armeabi/"